# Strange Smarty Variable Behavior With Input Fields

Tags: php, model-view-controller, smarty

I am encountering some odd behavior with Smarty but I believe solution is fairly simple. I am admittedly not an expert w/ Smarty but I still find this rather strange.

Some background, `$PF_SHOP_CART_GIFTS` is an integer, either 0 if no gifts are in cart or a positive number if gifts do exist in the cart.

I have a section loop defined as the following:

```
{if $PF_SHOP_CART_GIFTS}
<input type="text" name="iGifts" value="{$PF_SHOP_CART_GIFTS}" />
{section name="gift_memberships" loop=$PF_SHOP_CART_GIFTS}
 // A bunch of stuff happens here but it isn't related to my question
{/section}
{/if}
```

The problem is that the value of the input field "iGifts" always ends up being NULL (value="" when I view source) which is weird because if I just output the smarty variable:

```
{$PF_SHOP_CART_GIFTS}
```

I see the correct integer value that it is set to.  Is there something that prevents me from using smarty variables in the context of input field values?

Comment: What appens if you replace the posted code with **[this](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=9Se8PYfk)**?

Comment: @lorenzo-s that is the strangest part, it outputs "Value of $PF_SHOP_CART_GIFTS is 3", yet the value of the input field still == "".

Comment: Are you sure?!? Is there something that can replace the content of the form at runtime (Javascript, for example?). Try to extend your question with a little bit of code or upload the page on Pastebin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up rewriting part of the controller that inits the form.  All data is now accessible (in a logical fashion) and life is good. /phew

Comment: There was no apparent way to get this data to work as an input field value in the TPL until rewriting the controller which still makes very little sense to me...